# I can't seem to understand how partitions work, and I don't know how much is dedicated to each OS in my computer

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I recently fell in love with Ubuntu, and installed it in my computer. A laptop that had a special discount because it was associated with the school or something. Anyways.

It came with 2 OS: Windows 7 and Linux Magic Box (translation of "Linux Caixa Mágica", something that was supposed to help learning but it sucks). I then installed Ubuntu in what I thought that it was a 103GB partition, but upon further investigation I think I actually only gave it 7GB! It was exactly the other way around I wanted.

So, on the boot screen (where I can choose the 3 different OS) it showed 2 different parts for the Linux Magic Box: "/dev/sda2" and /dev/sda5. I tried to delete the /dev/sda 5, but is says that it has to delete the logical ones higher than 5... or something along those lines. I can post the full error message if needed :) The /dev/sda2 deleted without any problems.

Here is my GParted screen:

[image]

As you can see, there is indeed some more space left for allocating. But there are tons of different partitions! I wanted to delete almost all of them, but I'm afraid I might screw up.

This is what shows up in Windows 7 Computer (please never mind the text being in Portuguese, I think it's understandable)

[image]

As you can see, I have 2 discs: /c/ and /d/. So it should be 2 partitions, correct? I really don't understand it.

My idea is to keep Windows 7 installed, and Ubuntu installed alongside them as well, removing only the Magic Box, this releasing more space for Ubuntu. But what seems like a simple task actually turned not to be quite so.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume F: is a removable disc that was not present when you made the disc layout image from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't understand linux partitions, so it doesn't show them in the file manager. If you open windows's partition manager (which I forgot how to access) you will see all the partitions.

You have 3 primary partitions: `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda3`, `/dev/sda4`

`/dev/sda4` is an extended partition, it is divided up into 4 logical partitions: `/dev/sda5`, `/dev/sda6`, `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8`.

You just have to resize those partitions with gparted and take the unallocated space. E.g make `/dev/sda8` bigger by extending it to the left until `/dev/sda6`.

You can also delete any partition, but as your error message said, you have to first unmount the partitions which have a higher logical number. That means that while `/dev/sda8` is mounted you can't delete `/dev/sda5`. The easiest thing when you have to manipulate the partitions is to just boot up a live CD and start gparted there and do your job, because in a live session none of your partitions on the HDD are mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok 1st some basic stuff. In linux devices are shown as:

```
/dev/sdXN
```

- ... where X is a disc starting from a=1st disc, b=2nd disc.
- ... where N is a partition. 1=1st partition, 2=2nd partition

Windows insists on having its boot always on the 1st partition.

So

- /dev/sda1 is your C: drive.
- That disc has unallocated space of 48 Gb. More than enough for a Linux/Ubuntu install but I would advice to format it in Windows and either add it to C: or create an E:.
- /dev/sda3 seems to be a pre-installed diagnostics (probably a partition that is used for a re-install of your Windows. If you create a installation DVD you can remove this. If you delete it do that 1st and add it to the new E: drive or C: drive (you can use gParted for it but also Windows itself or a tool like Partition Magic.
- /dev/sda4 is your D: drive.
- /dev/sda5, sda7 and sda8 are Linux (ext is the default filesystem of Linux). sda8 is swap. The other 2 are weird: I would expect to see a label `/`. 1 is probably Ubuntu and 1  Linux Magic Box.

If I was you I would move the contents of /dev/sda5 (the FAT32) to your C: or D: drive.  It is then possible to remove ALL of the partitons named sda4 up to sda8 and create 2 or 3 new partions (1 for swap (2-5Gb should do), 1 for root (/; 15Gb should do) and 1 for your data (this is the equivalent of your D: drive for Ubuntu).

The result would be a clean install of Ubuntu with root on sda5, swap on sda6 and a data partition on sda7.

You can do all of this from the installer and if you do decide to format make them all ext4 and not ext4 or ext2.

If you want to KEEP any data on the Ubuntu disc you can also install gParted and make sda8 larger by adding the unallocated space between sda8 and sda8. It is a bit more complex though. The easiest method is to make a [gParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php); it works the same as Ubuntu Live DVD but that one is solely for disc management.

There is no need for an extra FAT32 partitions: Ubuntu will happily mount C: and D: for you so you can put files on D: and see them from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

With Linux structure, a small portion of hard drive is being used for booting up only. After the OS is being loaded and sync-ed with kernel (BIOS of your motherboard), it'll then mount your main partition where / and /home/yourusername is located.

typical structure that is common among Ubuntuians:

sda1 master disk (where your GRUB resides) - classified as "primary partition"

sda2 as extended partition. you will never see that partition because it is a "box" that hold "boxes" such as your sda5 - thus classified as "extended partition".

sda5 as logical partition where all of your main directory resides in. (i.e. / or /home/yourusername or such).

These structures are what enable Linux to operate. So, these files above are what control and assist in swapping and mounting these partitions so that way your OS can be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest keep Windows partition `sda1`, swap `sda7`, Ubuntu partition `sda8` *(probably, according to your Q)* [and diagnostics `sda3`, if you want to!].

#### The steps:

- Backup the desired contents of `sda6`,
- Boot Live-Ubuntu and start `GParted`,
- Right click the swap partition `sda7` and turn swap off,
- Among the logical partitions, delete `sda5` and `sda6` so that you have around 112GB of unallocated space in the extended partition. Use this to expand your `sda8` partition (recommended) or create a new logical partition; or somewhere in between.
- Keep `sda3` if you want to, else delete and create a primary partition with the unallocated space succeeding `sda1`.
- Go to *Edit* menu and select *apply the pending operations*.

[image: snap1]